# time.Time conversion to gorm's timestamptz when creating postgres database records

Tags: postgresql, go, timestamp, go-gorm

Creating a simple `User` model record in a postgres database using gorm.io from json produces the following error which inhibits the record from being saved.

```
cannot convert 2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST to Timestamptz
[1.166ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","first_name","last_name","dob") VALUES ('2021-12-26 06:58:30.439','2021-12-26 06:58:30.439',NULL,'Jenny','Langston','2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST') RETURNING "id"
```

When implementing the `Scanner`, `Valuer`, `UnmarshalJSON` methods the time value is not converted to the correct `postgres` timestamp format. Tags are set in the `User` model as shown below.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql/driver"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

func pgSetup() *gorm.DB {
    var dsn string = `
        host=localhost
        user=postgres
        password=postgres
        dbname=mydbname
        port=5432`
    pg, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        panic("Bad database connection")
    }

    return pg
}

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    FirstName string      `json:"firstName"`
    LastName  string      `json:"lastName"`
    DOB       Timestamptz `json:"dob" gorm:"type:timestamptz"`
}

type Timestamptz struct {
    time.Time
}

func (t *Timestamptz) UnMarshal(b []byte) error {
    if b[0] == '"' && b[len(b)-1] == '"' {
        b = b[1 : len(b)-1]
    }

    // take care of null..
    if len(b) == 0 || string(b) == "null" {
        t.Time = time.Time{}
        return nil
    }

    err := t.UnmarshalJSON(b)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func (t *Timestamptz) Scan(b interface{}) error {
    switch x := b.(type) {
    case time.Time:
        t.Time = x
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("unsupported scan type %T", b)
    }
    return nil
}

func (t *Timestamptz) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    // check if the date was not set..
    if t.Time.IsZero() {
        return nil, nil
    }
    return t.Time.Format(time.RFC3339), nil
}

func (t *Timestamptz) GormDataType() string {
    return "TIMESTAMPTZ"
}

func main() {
    pg := pgSetup()
    jsonStr := `{
        "firstName":"FirstName",
        "lastName":"LastName",
        "dob":"2006-01-02T15:04:05-07:00"}`
    var record User

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &record)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    pg.Create(&record)
    fmt.Println(record)
}
```

How can the correct format be set during record creation from gorm.io?
Do the `date` and `time` portions of the timestamp need to be saved separately?

Comment: Using time.Time directly should just work (as opposed to wrapping it in your own type). Have you tried that?

Comment: @Peter Thanks that works like a charm. Looks like I ended up going down a rabbit hole. Had a typo in my original timestamp string that sent me looking for random fixes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use time.Time directly in the User struct